# D3 check if mouse position inside a rectangle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I have a treemap made of rect elements placed one in top of the others. Given the x,y position of the mouse I would like to get all the rectangles "under" that point (see sketch).
Is there any way of doing that without having to check if the mouse position is inside the area for every rect element on the treemap?

[image: Sketch]

Comment: You could use a [quadtree](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom).

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthof for the hint. Anyhow I'm not completely sure I can use quadtree for visualising a software...

Comment: No, the quadtree would be only for checking which rectangles the point is in.